# Thunderbird - Login Script to create user and email account

Tags: active-directory, scripting, login, automation, thunderbird

Is there anything out there that will let me script via active directory and login scripts the creation of a thunderbird user profile and associated email account?

I looked to do this in Outlook 2010, however due to outlooks current slow preformance with IMAP4 servers its not really a viable option for us. so I am looking to script thunderbird as best I can.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here it's my autoconfiguration script for Thunderbird:
http://www.tutorialepc.ro/thunderbird-configuration-script.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be done.

One way is to rollup your sleeves and build most of the profile by yourself. Extensive information what files and directories are needed can be found at http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Thunderbird

The other way is to instruct Thunderbird on how to build the user's default profile. You can find additional information here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/MCD

Comment: thanks for the reply, its taken me a little while to get through the MCD article but it does not appear to be for the current version of thunderbird (v8) and parts of the article even refer to v1 and v2 is there likely to be any more upto date article on this subject?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I could find to fix this in a way that was acceptable to our company was to build a thunderbird profile manually using a VB script.

How I did this was fairly easy, I took a clean PC installed the latest TB version and configured an account as it was required for a user, I then lifted a copy of the profile folder in here there was a number of files that TB required and were nothing but plain text.

One of these files was the TB profile config file, I took this and build a VB script to manage the customisations per user.